# Best way to assess statistically significant differences between average days between different groups

Tags: statistical-significance

I have been tasked with looking at statistically significant differences in the average number of days between Event A and Event B for a number of sites within my organisation. This is not my area of expertise. Could anyone please advise which types of statistical tests/processes they would undertake with data such as the below so I can undertake research on how to take things forward? Thank you.

| Site | Observations | Average Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 6.3 |
| 2 | 250 | 4.4 |
| 3 | 600 | 8.7 |

Comment: If in addition to the averages per day and site you also have the standard deviations, you could run pairwise t-tests. Alternatively, if you have the underlying raw data, you could do a simple one-way ANOVA. With your sample size, the non-normality of data within sites is likely not an issue. (If variance was *very* different between sites, that might have more of an impact.)